# Java, localhost и HTML: страница авторизации

Tags: java, html, swing, localhost, jtextfield

Добавлять строки или данные из БД на веб-страницу - не проблема.

```java
Headers headers = HttpExchange.getRequestHeaders();
for (String header : headers.keySet()) {
    builder.append("<p>" + "</p>");
}
```

Можно ли таким образом вставить текстовое поле? И какие инструменты использовать: Java или HTML? Пытался создать JTextField и просто закинуть его в append, но появляется просто объект со своими характеристиками, а не визуальная форма поля ввода.

```java
JTextField field = new JTextField(15);

Headers headers = t3.getRequestHeaders();
for (String header : headers.keySet()) {
    builder.append("<p>" + field + "</p>");
}
```

В выводе:

*javax.swing.JTextField[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.BorderUIResource$CompoundBorderUIResource@6c7b053a,flags=296,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],disabledTextColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51],selectionColor=javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource[r=184,g=207,b=229],columns=15,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]*

Comment: Используйте шаблонизатор и mvc

Answer (score 2):

Не надо путать `Swing` и `HTML`!

`Swing` позволяет внутри элементов отображать `HTML`, а вот `HTML` внутри себя элементы `Swing` не отображает.

Пишите на `HTML`:

```java
Headers headers = HttpExchange.getRequestHeaders();

for (String header : headers.keySet()) {
    builder.append("<input value='" + header + "'>");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Всё заработало.